# Change default timezone not working for cookies

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, timestamp

I am trying to check the value of a cookie every 30 seconds, on the client side. I am using [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to do this.

So I'm setting the cookie using `setcookie()` in PHP. My code:

```
setcookie('cookiename','value', time() + (60 * 10));
```

After I checked with [Chrome's Web Developer Toolbar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm), I noticed the expiration was several hours in the future. So, I double checked the time that my installation of Apache had; sure enough, it was wrong. It was some 7 hours ahead.

So I changed it using `date_default_timezone_set()`, and double checked the new time with `date("h:i:s", time())` and it looked good.

Problem is, the change isn't affecting the cookie's expire time! It's still 7 hours ahead.

Is this a known issue? I have Googled and found nil.

**Update**

Ok so after some talk with @ficuscr, we deduced that `time()` doesn't get affected by timezone change. When using it in conjunction with `date()`, i.e. `date("H:i:s", time())`, then the timezone *is* reflected.

So since this is expected behaviour in PHP, I guess **this is now a Javascript issue.**

Comment: I did read the docs. But if I'm doing `time() + (60 * 10)`, it will set it to 10 minutes in the future for GMT. The client is not GMT (and it will always be in the same timezone)

Comment: Reset the cookie.  Don't expect this to retroactivly change a set cookie.

Comment: I've manually deleted it to make sure. Problem is still there

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/i5PnKdRNKgY maybe?  Remove the third party tool from the equation.  Suppose wait 10 minutes and if you can still access page dig further :)

Comment: Good call. Still giving me the same time though.

I think it has to do with the fact that cookies are supposed to be set in relation to GMT. Perhaps Chrome is not normalizing timezones?

Comment: ... https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/SQU5ExNQSOY/NaGsqugXLccJ

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48723/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-martin)